# Question about the conformal mapping classes

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

currently I am trying the solve the following exercise about conformal mappings. Consider the following conformal mapping classes:
$$
\mathcal{C}_1 := \{f \text{ conformal on }\mathbb D \mid f(z) = z + a_2 z^2 + a_3z^3+\dots \; \in \mathbb D\} \\
\mathcal{C}_2 := \{g \text{ conformal on } \hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D \mid g(z) = z+b_0+\frac{b_1}{z}+\frac{b_2}{z^2}+\dots \; \in \hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D\}
$$
Consider $f \in \mathcal{C}_1$ then prove that $\frac{1}{f(1/z)} \in \mathcal{C}_2$ and $0 \notin g(\hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D$) and that one has
$$
g(z) = z -a_2+\frac{a^2_2-a_3}{z}+\dots.
$$

**What I was able to prove so far**: Consider any $f \in \mathcal{C}_1$ with $f(0)=0$ and denote $g(z):=\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$. Since $f(1/z)$ has a zero at infinity, we know that $g$ has a (simple) pole at infinity. But then $g(1/z)$ has a simple pole at $0$, hence $g(z)$ has a simple pole at infinity and since $g$ is analytic in $\hat{\mathbb{C}} - \mathbb{D} \cup \{\infty\}$ one has that the Laurent series around infinity must be given by
$$
g(z) = z + b_0 + \frac{b_1}{z}+\frac{b_2}{z^2}+\dots,
$$
in other words $g \in \mathcal{C}_2$. Next suppose that $0 \in g(\hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D)$ then there exsits some $w \in \hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D$ such that $g(w)=0$ but then $\frac{1}{w} \in \mathbb D$ and since $f(z) = \frac{1}{g(1/z)}$ this implies that $\lim_{z \to 1/w} |f(z)| = +\infty$ hence $1/w$ would be a pole for $f$ in $\mathbb D$ but this directly contradicts the given Laurent expansion of $f$ in $\mathbb D$ (since $a_{-1} = 0$) that is given by $\mathcal{C}_1$. But now I am stuck for the last part.

**My idea**: Since $|g(z) - b_0 - z| \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$ we know that $g(z)-b_0-z$ has a zero at $\infty$ but then $g(1/z) - b_0 - \frac{1}{z}$ has a zero at $0$ exactly similiar to $f$ but I his does not help, so the question is how I can fully relate the coefficients of the Laurent series to one-another although the expansions are given around different points/in different domains.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiply term by term since $g(z)f(1/z)=1, |z|>1$ so you know $f(1/z)=1/z+a_2/z^2..$ and $g(z)=z+b_0 +b_1/z+...$ so the coefficient of $1/z$ is $0$ and $a_2+b_0$ respectively hence $b_0=-a_2$ and so on looking at the coefficients of $1/z^2,..$ which are $0$ on one hand and given recursively by $a,b$ on the other you find $b_1,b_2, ...$ too

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not think of this trick. The calculation is also clear, what remains unclear is the coefficient $b_0$. So far it seems to me that this exercise states that as soon as $f$ has the given form from $\mathcal{C}_1$ we automatically can get another conformal map in the region $\{|z|>1\}$ and even write out (locally) the Laurent  series, however why does (intuitively) the series of $g$ must contain the extra term $b_0$?

Comment: Not sure of what you ask - any meromorphic function at a simple pole has the structure: pole term + constant+ analytic terms that vanish there; at infinity pole is $z$, constant is $b_0$ and analytic terms vanishing at infinity the rest

Comment: Yes that is correct, I was just wondering if $b_0$ here has a special role or not? As I see it, it can could be $0$, on the other hand for the conformal map $f$ it was important that there is no such constant, since we needed $f(1/z)$ to have a zero at infinity. All in all: Having a conformal map $f$ on $\mathbb D$ with $f(0)=0$ one can always create a conformal map $1/f(1/z)$ for free, however the other way around one needs to have the extra condition that $0 \notin g(\hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D)$.

Comment: the condition $0 \notin g(\hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D)$ is just a normalization similar to the normalization $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$ for $f$ as any $g$ analytic on the disc exterior and conformal at infinity with a simple pole with residue $1$ can be translated to get $0 \in E$ the complement of its image; similarly with $b_0$ that is equal with $-f''(0)/2$ so it has that meaning if you wish, though it is not that important in the theory; the important class is the one where $E$ has measure $0$

Comment: I am not sure I understand everything, that $0 \notin g(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$ is just the right normalization similiar to $f(0)=0, f^{\prime}(0) = 1$. What you are then implying is that $0 \notin g(\hat{\mathbb C} - \mathbb D)$ does not matter in the sence that it is possible to translate $g$ such that $0$ is in the complement of the translated function?  I guess $E$ here is the complement of the image? Why does $-f^{\prime \prime}(0)/2$ imply $0 \in E$

Comment: Yes $E$ is the complement of the image; what I meant is that $b_0=-f''(0)/2$ so $b_0$ doesn't have a special meaning; the fact that $0 \in E$ is again nothing special as one can translate $g$; what is important is if $E$ has zero measure or not because of the area theorem - when $g$ is univalent as above then $\sum n|b_n|^2 \le 1$ with equality iff $E$ has measure $0$ which implies that $|b_1| \le 1$ and that is the basis of the fundamental theorems in geometric function theory (eg Koebe one-quarter theorem etc);

Comment: Alright, so the idea is that $0 \in E$ is not special but rather that due to the area theorem one can show that $\int_E dx dy = \pi r^2 - \pi \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} n |b_n|^2 r^{-2n}$ hence since $g$ is univalent as above then we can check that $\lambda(E) = 0$ iff $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} n |b_n|^2 = 1$. Similiary to the exercise, we can solve Koebe's one quarter (Wikipedia proof) by saying that $w \notin f(\mathbb D)$ then  $\frac{wf(z)}{w-f(z)}$ is univalent in $|z|<1$. Applying some inequality for the coefficients then yields $|w| \geq 1/4$.